# Did the opposition candidate for PM in Hungary's 2022 election only get 5 minutes on state TV?

Tags: politics, media, hungary

[Why the Polish Elections Cannot Be Repeated in Orbán's Hungary](https://revdem.ceu.edu/2023/10/23/why-the-polish-elections-cannot-be-repeated-in-orbans-hungary/):

> In the 2022 campaign, the opposition candidate for prime minister got a total of only five minutes (!) of airtime on state television.

Is this true? (BTW, that article also claims that "Orbán is both an autocrat and a criminal", which does give me the impression they might be making biased claims.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Guardian corroborates the claim](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/apr/02/hungary-independent-media-editors-reporters-orban).

> On Hungary’s national day last month Viktor Orbán accused the opposition of seeking to drag the country into Russia’s war on Ukraine.
>
> The Hungarian prime minister’s highly questionable claim was the centrepiece of a 30-minute speech to supporters that was broadcast on the state TV channel M1 nine times in 24 hours. For Orbán, it was perfect coverage, as he seeks a fourth straight term in the country’s most closely fought election in years, on 3 April. ***The main opposition leader, Péter Márki-Zay, has also been on state TV: he got five minutes.***

> ...it was hard to find coverage of this week’s press conference by Márki-Zay at a Habsburg estate reportedly owned by the prime minister’s father, Gyözö Orbán. Márki-Záy hammered away at one of his main themes: corruption. Pro-government news sites, such as Origo and Magyar Nemzet, did not mention the speech, nor did Hungary’s main news agency, MTI. The last-discovered reference the agency made to the Hatvanpuszta estate, alleged to have been subject to a lavish renovation, was more than 20 years ago.

The article goes on to describe Hungary's waning independent media.

> ....the erosion of Hungary’s independent media has been unfolding since Orbán was elected again in 2010. His victory was soon followed by a media law that asserted government control over the main media regulator. In later years, independent newspapers and websites went bankrupt or were taken over by government-friendly buyers, squeezed, in part, by state advertising heavily tilted towards pro-government outlets.

Answer (score 5):

The opposition candidate for Prime Minister of Hungary (in the most recent election held on 3 April 2022) was Péter Márki-Zay. He stated that opposition politicians are entitled to only five minutes of airtime on Hungarian public television. Via an interview with Márki-Zay, [Meet the conservative who could unseat Viktor Orbán](https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/peter-marki-zay-viktor-orban-hungary-opponent-election-interview/), published 14 January 2022 on website openDemocracy:

> “Opposition politicians cannot get any airtime on public television
> paid for by our taxpayers’ money,” Márki-Zay says. “In the four-year
> cycle, an entire opposition party can only get five minutes airtime on
> public television...

This was confirmed by Euronews on 29 March 2022, [Claims of media bias...](https://www.euronews.com/2022/03/29/claims-of-media-bias-overshadow-hungarian-election-campaign):

> When Hungarian state TV was obliged by electoral law to give airtime
> to opposition candidate Péter Márki-Zay - it ran an interview early in
> the morning that lasted just five minutes.

In the following passage from the same openDemocracy article, note the reference to **televised debates** ahead of the opposition primary to select the prime ministerial candidate:

> ...the international press anointed Budapest mayor Gergely Karácsony in
> the autumn, dark horse Péter Márki-Zay was making a splash in
> televised debates ahead of an unprecedented opposition primary to
> select its prime ministerial candidate. Karácsony, a political
> pollster by trade, saw the writing on the wall. Stepping aside, he
> cleared the way for a Márki-Zay victory...

If televised debates are allowed, then television broadcasts featuring opposition candidates are clearly possible, although the premise of the question remains correct: Air time on Hungarian **PUBLIC** television MDTV is limited to five minutes for the opposition parties. See too: [After Four Years of Neglect, State Media Gives Five Minutes to Each Opposition Party before Election](https://hungarytoday.hu/public-state-media-opposition-fidesz-bias-media-freedom-election/) via Hungary Today in English ([and in German](https://ungarnheute.hu/news/in-den-letzten-4-jahren-konnte-die-opposition-in-den-staatlichen-medien-kaum-zu-wort-kommen-16192/)).

Drawing from Hungarian and non-Hungarian sources, the answer is yes, the **opposition candidate** for prime minister in 2022 only received five minutes of public television airtime.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty for the slightly more cross-checked answer, but I'll tick the accept mark (which doesn't affect answer ordering here IIRC) on the other one for adding some detail/contrast with how much coverage Orban himself got in the same venue(s).

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat thank you for awarding me the bounty. I looked around for sources for awhile, but only felt much confidence in these three and The Guardian. Orban and the former president of Poland get a lot of negative press for being autocrats (I agree with you that 'criminal' was extreme!) but I was temperate in what I wrote about Orban, as openDemocracy is a George Soros publication. Soros sponsored media gets a lot of justifiable flack but they aren't pro-war. The Guardian isn't either, but it is a UK publication so Ukraine coverage is often positive since 2020.